# Search string same how not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to perform a simple search and I cant find out what I have missed here 
This is my ( I think very simple code)

```
public ActionResult WeeklyVorts(string sortOrder, string searchString, int page = 1  )
{

    ViewData["corentSort"] = sortOrder;
    ViewData["productSortParm"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Product desc" : "";

    var weeklyS = from c in _repository.List().OrderBy(x=>x.UParasha) select c;

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        weeklyS = weeklyS.Where(v => v.UHeadLine.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
            || v.UParasha.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
            || v.Uvort.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())


    );
    }

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "Product desc":
            weeklyS = weeklyS.OrderByDescending(s => s.UHeadLine);
            break;
        default:
            weeklyS = weeklyS.OrderBy(d => d.UParasha);
            break;
    }




    ViewData["weeklyS"] = _repository.List().ToList();
    int hlist = (_repository.List().Count());
    ViewData["TotalPages"] = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)hlist / PageSize);
    ViewData["CurrentPage"] = page;
    return View(_repository.List().Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
            }
```

My View

```
<div class="search">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
    { %>
        <p>
            Find: <%=Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewData["currentFilter"] as string) %> &nbsp;
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p> 
    <%} %>

</div>


//in a brackpoint I can c that the typed parameter is pass to 
//   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
```

I know I have missed same thing in my view I just cand find out what
Thanks

Comment: why don't you debug it and see what happens?

Comment: I did , the page is just refresh -I think the problem is in my view (<div class="search">
 <% using (Html.BeginForm())
    { %>
  <p>
   Search: <%=Html.TextBox("searchString", (string)ViewData["currentFilter"])%> &nbsp;
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </p> 
    
                <%} %>

</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are assigning the `weeklyS` variable into your `ViewData["weeklyS"]`

try this

```
ViewData["weeklyS"] = weeklyS;
```

instead of this

```
ViewData["weeklyS"] = _repository.List().ToList();
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when using   ViewData["weeklyS"] = weeklyS;>>>Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 45:             if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
Line 46:             {
Line 47:                 weeklyS = weeklyS.Where(v => v.UHeadLine.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())

Answer (score 1):

your code have some lines that I can not understand

why do you use `_repository` after searching should you use `weeklyS` variable?

try this

```
ViewData["weeklyS"] = weeklyS.ToList();
int hlist = weeklyS.Count();
ViewData["TotalPages"] = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)hlist / PageSize);
ViewData["CurrentPage"] = page;
return View(weeklyS.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
```

Comment: the same Error MSG :Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 45:             if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
Line 46:             {
Line 47:                 weeklyS = weeklyS.Where(v => v.UHeadLine.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())

Comment: The stack trace says the value of `weeklys` came from `var weeklyS = from c in _repository.List().OrderBy(x=>x.UParasha) select c;` is null try that `var weeklyS = (from c in _repository.List() select c).OrderBy(x=>x.UParasha);`

Comment: When using { var weeklyS = (from c in _repository.List() select c).OrderBy(x => x.UParasha);
)
I'm getting in the ( weeklyS = weeklyS.Where(x => x.UHeadLine.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
An error saying :" An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
I have tried running it without the if{}, and place a breakpoint when it has reached it I still had null in the results

Comment: try to redeclare `weeklys` using its type instead of anonymous type `var weeklyS`. try `List<myType> weeklys` where  `myType` is the type of items return by your query.